# php code to delete value table 2 from value of table 1

Tags: php

I am php beginner.
I would like to read email contain in table 1 and with the value selected deleted the corresponding email of the table 2 ?
May you provide me some info to manage it ?

select email_table1 from table1.
delete from table2 where email = email_table1.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: This would probably get more response with a relevant database tag (MySQL?) as opposed to PHP.

Comment: Question is unclear, you didn't provide proper details of the table fields or sample values. Impossible to be sure what the exact solution is. Please add details. Also, PHP is probably irrelevant here, please re-tag with SQL and also the name of your database product (e.g. mysql or whatever you're using)

Answer (score 1):

There's little information to form an answer but you could use a sub select.
Something like this presuming you're using MySQL or similar.

```
DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE id = (
    SELECT `referenceID` FROM `table2` WHERE `email` = 'the@email.com' LIMIT 1
) LIMIT 1;
```